# Lost ubuntu while recovering mbr

Tags: mbr

I have Ubuntu 13.04(32 bit) and Windows 7.

I restored my MBR from Ubuntu using terminal(did not use recovery CD).

When I rebooted, the Windows MBR booted to Windows directly. I want to have Ubuntu option in MBR.

What can I do to fix this?  (I dont want to reinstall grub I just want to have ubuntu option in mbr)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the directions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

You're basically re-installing grub on the boot drive.